# SQL-how to select only doubles/date/timeStamps/time/strings values from a string column?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, ignite

I have a raw data duration column values like

```
| duration |
 100
 50
 2.3
 4.2
 1.23
 1996/09/02
 12-05-1997
 12-05-1997 10:20:05
 stack Overflow
 10:02:28
```

From above duration column, I want to filter out and see each type of the values to do pre-process. So i want to extract only Double values (2.3, 4.2, 1.23), and select only for Date values ( 1996/09/02,  12-05-1997),
select only timeStamps (12-05-1197 10:20:05), only time values (10:02:28)
and only strings (stack Overflow)

What are the select queries I have to pick for each of the categories ?

Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: so your output should just have 2.3,4.2,1.23,1996/09/02,12-05-1997? right?

Comment: A little database design goes a long way. How come you have such Different types of data all in the same column

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following using `REGEXP`

(In regex, ^ means begin, and $ means end)

```
SELECT t1
FROM test 
WHERE t1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' != 1 
or t1 like '%.%'
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0af4d/3

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data, you can use `like`.

For "double" values, you can use:

```
where duration like '%.%'
```

And for dates:

```
where duration like '%-%-%' or duration like '%/%/%'
```

These are *not* general purpose.  But they work for the data you have provided and `like` might be faster than regular expressions.